# How do I persist users as they browse my site? Node.JS

Tags: javascript, session, authentication, node.js

When a user logs into my site, I need to persist that login session. Of course, this is done using sessions/cookies.  In Django, this is built in.

But in Node.js, how do I persist this? I'm looking at connect-auth module: https://github.com/ciaranj/connect-auth

But it doesn't seem like it handles persistence...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[node-sessions](https://github.com/samsonjs/node-sessions) library is one option. Rolling out your own also should not be too difficult.